# Hanging main thread in loop

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm using synchronization in one "pool thread" and main thread. In pool thread I lock section with `synchronization(locker)` and then I perform:

```
synchronization(locker){
   QueuePool.shutdownNow();
   while(!QueuePool.isShutDown()){}
   //do something after

    QueuePool.SetThreadQueue(null);

    QueuePool queue = QueuePool.GetThreadQueue();

    Pallets pallets = Pallets.GetPallets(context);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (String key : pallets.getPalletsToSend().keySet()) {
        for (HashMap<String, String> object : pallets.getPalletsToSend().get(key)) {
            PalletSender sender = new PalletSender(object, context);
            queue.addTask(sender);
        }
    }
}
```

and on main thread this synchronization is when button click:

```
synchronized (QueuePool.locker2){QueuePool.GetThreadQueue().addTask(palletSender);}
```

QueuePool is a singleton having ThreadPoolExecution. In SetThreadQqueue I clear singleton instance on null.

the pool thread is run every 2 minute. It's possible that it will first go to the pool thread. So how long it can take when waiting on `while(!QueuePool(isShutDown())`? Maybe I can add some code to add one more condition in that loop? I am not sure I'm correct. Let me know what is the best.

Comment: You should copy the whole code, it's not easy to understand a question put down like this

Comment: You can use `awaitTermination(...)` instead of the loop, also, keep in mind that after you call `shutdownNow()` the pool won't complete the submited tasks and it won't accept new ones.

Comment: Your current code is definitely bad for two reasons. One, you have a tight spin loop that just burns CPU while waiting for something to happen. When you need something to happen, you don't want to be burning the CPU because your consuming the resources needed for stuff to happen. Two, you're waiting while holding a lock. That causes all kinds of problems, including often deadlock.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what should I do then ?

Comment: @PatrykImosa remove the lock, use a method which doesn't busy wait, i.e. awaitTermination.  Are you sure you even need to wait for termination?

Comment: After shutdown I'm setting QueuePool on null and then I create a new instance.

Comment: @PatrykImosa It's kind of hard to say, because you should never have this code in the first place. Whatever design decisions led you to this place should be rethought. If you must do an ugly quick fix, you can change the logic to something like `while (1) { synchronized(obj) { if (isShutDown()) break; } sleep(a_bit); } synchronized(obj) { do_stuff; }`. This way, at least you're sleeping without holding the lock while you wait rather than spinning while holding the lock.

Comment: But what about putting there awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ?